# dplyr comma (,) syntax appears broken

Tags: r, dplyr

```
# Code chunk 1
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = c(NA, 1, 2), b = c(5, 5, 5))
```

Please create the data frame above. If you then run this code chunk 2

```
# Code chunk 2 
df %>%
   mutate(
     c = abs(lag(a, 1) - a),
     d = sum(.$c, na.rm = TRUE) / (length(.$c) - 1)
   )
```

you get this error *"Unknown or uninitialised column: 'c'."*. Yet I can run the same code, arranged differently, and get what I desire (no errors, proper output).

```
# Code chunk 3
df %>%
  mutate(c = abs(lag(a, 1) - a)) %>%
  mutate(d = sum(.$c, na.rm = TRUE) / (length(.$c) - 1))
```

Why doesn't the second code chunk work? I don't want to have to string together a series of `mutate(x) %>% mutate(y) %>% mutate(z) %>% etc.` when a simple `mutate(x, y, z)` is much tidier.

Comment: In your code chunk 2 the dot refers to the data set that is input into the whole mutate and this data set has'nt a c column yet.

Comment: @Nicolas2 if my `code chunk 2` doesn't "have the `c` column yet", then how does SmitM's code work below, which also references `c`? If the `c` column doesn't "exist" yet. What's the difference?

Comment: Because SmitM doesn't use the dot notation. Within a pipe, the dot contains the result of the previous step. That's also why your third chunk works : the dot refers to the first mutate result which has the c column added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working fine. You need to modify a bit of your code.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    c = abs(lag(a, 1) - a),
    d = sum(c, na.rm = TRUE) / (length(c) - 1)
  )
```

Change the `.$c` to just `c`

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = abs(lag(a) - a),
          d = sum(c, na.rm = TRUE)/(n() - 1))
```

Comment: so is `n()` a wrapper (is that the correct word) for `length()`? Can you expand on that?

Comment: @stackinator  `n()` in dplyr gives the number of rows.  It is similar to `length` in that `length` gives the number of elements in that column